# Apache Camel - from jms to http

Tags: http, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a spring-boot project using Apache Camel.
I want to read a message from an activemq queue containing a file and send it to a web server.

I am trying to find the proper way to do this.

I believe I can make something like:

```
from("activemq:queue").bean(MyBean.class, "process")
```

And manually build a http request but I can't help thinking there is probably a better way to do it. Like:

```
from("activemq:queue").bean(MyBean.class, "process")
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,constant("POST"))
  .to("http://localhost:8080/test");
```

But I don't know how to manipulate the "exchange" to have a valid http Message.

MyBean receives an Exchange object containing a JmsMessage. I see that there is also a HTTPMessage but I don't think I should build that manually. (It requires HTTPRequest and Response objects I am not sure how to get.)

Can someone shed some light on this problem?

**Update**
I am going for the bean solution.

```
from("activemq:queue").bean(MyBean.class, "sendMultipart");


public void sendMultipart(Exchange exchange) {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) exchange.getIn().getBody());
    InputStreamBody contentBody = new InputStreamBody(in, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), "filename");
    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder
            .create()
            .addPart("file", contentBody)
            .build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/upload/");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(httpResponse);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "valid http Message"? You want to transform the data received on the jms endpoint to sent on using http?

Comment: @rparree Yes. But I want to build a custom url based on the message I received. For instance, I want to get a particular header from the jms message and use it as a path parameter for my url, and the jms message content I want to send it as the POST body.

Comment: The docs say you can set a header with key: Exchange.HTTP_URI. So, the trick would be to formulate an RHS expression, based on your JMS headers. Are the values available as headers on the Camel exchange?

Comment: @DariusX. They are. That part I got figured out. I can reach my http endpoint. I can't figure out how to send the message content. The jms message has a body consisting of String with, what I believe, are a file bytes. So I have to send that as the body of a POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated post

I found this http://hilton.org.uk/blog/camel-multipart-form-data. It allows you to leverage the camel http component.

```scala
"jms:queue/SomeQ" ==> {
    process(toMultipart)
    setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data")
    process((e: Exchange) => e.getIn.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI,"http://localhost:8111/foo"))
    to ("http:DUMMY")
}

def toMultipart(exchange: Exchange): Unit = {

  val data = exchange.in[java.io.File]

  val entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
  entity.addBinaryBody("file", data)
  entity.addTextBody("name", "sample-data")

  // Set multipart entity as the outgoing message’s body…
  exchange.in = entity.build
}
```

Side note: this would really be a nice use-case to try-out reactive streams.

## Original post

I am still having some problems understanding your actual problem. Perhaps some code might help:

I am now assuming you are receiving bytes in some character encoding and want to sent it onward to a dynamically established http-endpoint.

Is the following something you are looking for (code is in camel's scala-dsl)

```scala
"jms:queue/SomeQ" ==> {
    convertBodyTo(classOf[String],"UTF-32" )
    process((e: Exchange) => e.in = e.in[String].toUpperCase + "!")
    process((e: Exchange) => e.getIn.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI,"http://localhost:8111/foo"))
    to ("http:DUMMY")
}
```

It will be send as an HTTP POST as the body is not null.

I receive it all well on another endpoint i created to ensure the code above is correct:

```or-tag-here
"jetty:http://localhost:8111/foo" ==> {
  log("received on http 8111 endpoint ${body}")
 }
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying something else: 
from("activemq:queue").bean(MyBean.class, "sendMultipart");
Now I just have to figure out how to send a multipart POST request.

Comment: what is the contents of the JMS message?

Comment: And what do those bytes represent? (in my assumption above i recon the bytes represented characters in a non-default encoding). Is it something else? Something binary (like an image/pdf/sound/movie?)

Comment: It represents some file. It can be a text file or even a .zip file.

Comment: In a stream or a raw byte[]. If the latter what does the camel route need to do with those bytes, just pass them on to a HTTP post multi-part? (BTW you might get into memory problems if the byte[] is too large)

Comment: Raw Byte[]. Check my updated question. That is somewhat working (it reaches my webservice).